# Getting average of results from group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Am trying to get the average likes count for each user where the offset is as close as possible to a value that i set(but still blow that value).

```
select id, max(likes), user_id
from lookups
where offset < 30
group by media_id;
```

The above query will return something like this:

```
id    likes    user_id
1       2       1
2       7       1
3       6       1
4       9       2
5       5       2 
6       5       2
7       2       3
8       3       3
```

i want to turn this in to average likes for each user, without counting the rows that would not be returned by the above query, so that the result of this would be:

```
average_likes     user_id
     5              1
     6.333          2
     2.5            3
```

How can i do this using sql?

Comment: same as `MAX()` you can use `AVG()`

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  You are aggregating by `media_id`, but choosing indeterminate values of `user_id` and `id`.

Comment: In my case that does not really matter, since a media always have the same user, so all the rows with media_id 5 will also have the user id 2 etc.. and i did not really want to pull out the id at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick your query in a subquery and `GROUP BY` again:

```
SELECT user_id,
    avg(maxlikes)
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        max(likes) AS maxlikes,
        user_id
    FROM lookups
    WHERE offset < 30
    GROUP BY ID, user_idd
    ) subquery
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: The subquery is going to return an arbitrary `id` and `user_id` within each `media_id` group, not the ones related to the row with the maximum likes.